# How should I have select unblocked comment on SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, inner-join

How should I have select unblocked comments

[image]

For example we have these tables and records,is it possible to show list of comments that one user wants to see ?

Something like this: list of comments who userId2(B) can see

Result must be:

```
{ 2, "Comment 3" & 2, "Comment 4" & 4, "Comment 6" }
```

Here is my wrong select:

```
SELECT        
    Comments.Comment, Comments.UserId
FROM            
    Users 
INNER JOIN
    Comments ON Users.UserId = Comments.UserId 
INNER JOIN
    Block ON Users.UserId = Block.BlockerId AND Users.UserId = Block.BlockedId
WHERE        
    (Block.BlockerId <> 2) 
    AND (Block.BlockedId <> 2) 
    AND (Users.UserId = 2)
```

Also here is link of my sample DB "testDB.bak":

[Click here to download(File size:200KB)](http://fs-m.com/TestDB.rar)

Thank you for helping me

Comment: Based on that screen shot, it would be SQL Server.

Comment: Yes, it's SQL server, I'm confusing to solve this problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
select a.UserId, a.Comment from Comments a
left join Block b
on a.UserId = b.BlockedId
and b.BlockerId = <your user here>
where b.BlockerId is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seem like this should work if I understand the rules:

```
SELECT * FROM Comments WHERE UserId NOT IN (SELECT BlockedId FROM Block WHERE BlockerId=2)
```

Comment: Thank you , it works too, but you are one minute late, anyway thank you